# About spotify popup

Tags: popup

I recently saw this:
[image]

if you open Spotify on chrome (not sure other browsers) and you click this button. It opens a popup. But it is different, it is a whole new Window, without any OS button. It also doesn't block this popup. How that work? I tried to find this in javascript code, but I didn't find it.

It is something new for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see now they are using Picture-in-picture:
https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/#example-add-custom-pip-button